# Setting a header based on an XQuery filter

Tags: apache-camel

I have a route that's set to run in batched mode, polling several thousand XML files. Each is timestamped inside the XML structure and this dateTime element is used to determine whether the XML should be included in the batch's further processing (an XQuery transform). As this is a batch route it self-terminates after execution.

Because the route needs to close itself I have to ensure that it also closes if every message is filtered out, which is why I don't use a filter but a `.choice()` statement instead and set a custom header on the exchange which is later used in a bean that groups matches and prepares a single source document for the XQuery.

However, my current approach requires a second route that both branches of the `.choice()` forward to. This is necessary because I can't seem to force both paths to simply continue. So my question is: how can get rid of this second route? One approach is setting the filter header in a bean instead but I'm worried about the overhead involved. I assume the XQuery filter inside Camel would greatly outperform a POJO that builds an XML document from a string and runs an XQuery against it.

```
from(sourcePath + "?noop=true" + "&include=.*.xml")
        .choice()
            .when()
                .xquery("[XQuery Filter]")
                .setHeader("Filtered", constant(false))
                .to("direct:continue")
            .otherwise()
                .setHeader("Filtered", constant(true))
                .to("direct:continue")
.end();

from("direct:continue")
        .routeId(forwarderRouteID)
        .aggregate(aggregationExpression)
            .completionFromBatchConsumer()
            .completionTimeout(DEF_COMPLETION_TIMEOUT)
            .groupExchanges()
        .bean(new FastQueryMerger(), "group")
        .to("xquery:" + xqueryPath)
        .bean(new FileModifier(interval), "setFileName")
        .to(targetPath)
        .process(new Processor() {
                @Override
                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                    new RouteTerminator(routeID, exchange.getContext()).start();
                    new RouteTerminator(forwarderRouteID, exchange.getContext()).start();
                }
            })
.end();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't .end() help here?
I mean the following:

```
from(sourcePath + "?noop=true" + "&include=.*.xml")
    .choice()
        .when()
            .xquery("[XQuery Filter]")
            .setHeader("Filtered", constant(false)).end()
        .otherwise()
            .setHeader("Filtered", constant(true)).end()
    .aggregate(aggregationExpression)
        .completionFromBatchConsumer()
        .completionTimeout(DEF_COMPLETION_TIMEOUT)
        .groupExchanges()
    .bean(new FastQueryMerger(), "group")
    .to("xquery:" + xqueryPath)
    .bean(new FileModifier(interval), "setFileName")
    .to(targetPath)
    .process(new Processor() {
            @Override
            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                new RouteTerminator(routeID, exchange.getContext()).start();
                new RouteTerminator(forwarderRouteID, exchange.getContext()).start();
            }
        });
```

just quickly tested the following one and it worked:

```
@Produce(uri = "direct:test")
protected ProducerTemplate testProducer;
@EndpointInject(uri = "mock:test-first")
protected MockEndpoint testFirst;
@EndpointInject(uri = "mock:test-therest")
protected MockEndpoint testTheRest;
@EndpointInject(uri = "mock:test-check")
protected MockEndpoint testCheck;

@Test
public void test() {
    final String first = "first";
    final String second = "second";
    testFirst.setExpectedMessageCount(1);
    testTheRest.setExpectedMessageCount(1);
    testCheck.setExpectedMessageCount(2);
    testProducer.sendBody(first);
    testProducer.sendBody(second);
    try {
        testFirst.assertIsSatisfied();
        testTheRest.assertIsSatisfied();
        testCheck.assertIsSatisfied();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() {
    return new RouteBuilder() {
        public void configure() {
            from("direct:test")
                .choice()
                    .when(body().isEqualTo("first")).to("mock:test-first")
                    .otherwise().to("mock:test-therest").end()
                    .to("mock:test-check");
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Took me quite a while to get back to this question as I've only just returned to this part of the project. The second code sample you give worked perfectly and was just what I needed. A simple `.end()` at the end of the whole `.choice()` statement terminates all branches. Your original first code section has two `.end()` statements which is incorrect and doesn't compile. I've modified it accordingly. Thanks again.